# Magento 2. Frontend. How do I subscribe to a property of my component

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

My question is pretty straight forward. I have JS component (an AMD module that extends from uiComponent) and I know I can make a property observable by specifying the `tracks` object in the `defaults` object for e.g.

```
defaults: { myProeperty: "Some Value", tracks: { myProperty: true }}
```

I wish now to **subscribe** to that change. For example execute a console.log every time **myProperty** value changes. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

A Variable will be subscribed when it's type observable `ko.observable`

**Your code will be like:**

```
Component.extend({
     ......
    myProeperty = ko.observable(false),
    ...............
    defaults: {
        myProeperty: "Some Value",
        tracks: {
            myProperty: true
        }
    },
    initialize: function() {
        self = this;
        this._super();
        this.myProeperty.subscribe(function(newValue) {
            console.log(newValue);

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there another way though? Another object in the defaults configuration? smth like subscribe { myProperty : myFunc } or anything that does not require to extend the initialize method?

Comment: I think you could use the import node.